# Twitter API v2 and chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, twitter, twitter-api-v2

I am trying to integrate Twitter in a chrome extension (private use only) but most of the tutorials require Node.js. Is there a way to communicate with Twitter API v2 client side only?

Answer (score 0):

It's an api, so it is accessible to anything that can communicate over HTTP, which you can do in the browser with [`fetch` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). Whether or not there are SDKs (software development kits; premade functions for communicating with an API) for twitter that are compatable with the browser is another question, which we can't answer here since that's "Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more; This question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers."

You can refer to the [Twitter API v2 Reference](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/api-reference-index) while crafting your use of the API if you're unable to find a library to help you.